# Hive create a flag value on existing table through SAS execute

Tags: hive, sas

I'm new to Hive, trying to create Hive tables through SAS studio over a server. I have been using execute statement to run HQL, yet I'm stuck on creating a simple flag value. I just want to assign '1' to every row in the exiting table event1.

The code I have has no errors, but the new variable, eventflag, cannot be found:

```
proc sql;
connect using cen0;
execute (create temporary table event1 as
        select x, y, z
        from lab.t2_clctn
        where z IN ('7','3')     
         )       
by cen0;

    execute (alter table event1 add columns(eventflag string)) by cen0;
    execute (insert into table event1 (eventflag) value('1')) by cen0;

quit;
```